# passing bootloader arguments to the kernel

Tags: linux, boot-loader, proc

We know that the bootloader parameters are passed to the kernel before the init process starts executing. What file in the /proc directory actually does this job?

Comment: This is a trick question.  As the answer reveals almost as an aside, _no_ file in the `/proc` directory does this job, because this job isn't done with files at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are speaking about `/proc/cmdline`:

```
$ cat /proc/cmdline 
BOOT_IMAGE=/boot/vmlinuz-3.2.0-4-amd64 root=UUID=8a03b651-2171-46f2-8314-14e4051136e6 ro console=tty0 console=ttyS0,9600n8
```

They are passed from bootloader to kernel according to [Multiboot specification](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiboot_Specification).